# Checkbox or Dropdown filter result

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, filter

I'm creating a website with a list of company and their profile. So far I have been able to make a navigation list of company and their profile as AJAX page.

```
<ul id="nav" style="float:left, margin: 10 10 0 10;">
    <li><a href="company_1">Company 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="company_2">Company 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="company_3">Company 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Here 's the AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
//initial
$('#content').load('content/index.php');

//handle menu clikcs
$('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
    return false;
});
```

});

And here 's one of company profile example:

```
<?php
$query = "select * from company_info where 1=1 and company_id = 1";

$run = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)){

    $company_id = $row[0];
    $company_name = $row[1];
    $company_website = $row[2];
    $company_email = $row[3];
    $company_facebook = $row[4];

echo "<h1>" . $company_name . "</h1>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><h3>Brief Introduction</h3></li>";
echo "<hr />";
echo "<li><h3>Contact Information</h3></li>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>Website: <a href='" . $company_website . "'>" . $company_website . "</a></li>";
echo "<li>Facebook: <a href='" . $company_facebook . "'>" . $company_facebook . "</a></li>";
//echo "<li>Email: <a href='mailto:5b.dznnkab@gmail.com'>" . $company_email . "</a></li>";
echo "<li>Email: <a href='mailto:" . $company_email . "'>" . $company_email . "</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
}
```

?>

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNNhQ.jpg

What I'm trying to achieve is to make either a dropdown list or checkbox or whichever method to filter the company. Let 's take an example, Company 1 and Company 2 are big companies, Company 3 is small companies. So the filter will have 2 options as Big and Small, and when the filter is submit, only the link of the suitable company will be left.

Any help is appreciated, and last, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all going to spoon feed you with code, but I'll explain you the method.

First, setup 2 Radio Button, and check with AJAX.

If the Radio Button 1 Value is 1, then show Big Companies.
If the Radio Button 2 Value is 1, then show small companies.
If both/none are 1 then show both.

You can do so by setting up column called company_size where it will be either l or s depending on the size. So once the userinput is received, filter all the inputs and get the data to output accordingly.

Comment: Yes I have done something similar to that and yes I have a company_size column, but what I'm trying to look for is to withdraw the link of the company after the filter

Comment: Yeah so if the check boxes are marked show a new list. You could do this with pure php but would require reloading the page